# C# Devexpress: Cast selected row to custom object

Tags: c#, gridview, casting, devexpress

In my grid I have a list of rows that come from a SQL DB (with a `SELECT * FROM` statement).

What I want to do is to let the user focus on a row -> click on a button and open a form with passing the row (in an entire object).

I tried this doing the following:

```
private void btn_Get_Object_Details_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Person p = gridView.GetFocusedRow() as Person;
     MessageBox.Show("name: " + person.Name);
}
```

I however get a nullreference exception for the `gridView.GetFocusedRow()` even though im selecting a row.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: What is the value of `gridView.GetFocusedRow()?.GetType()`?

Comment: `System.Data.DataRowView`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation, the [GetFocusedRow](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.GetFocusedRow.method) method's return value depends upon the type of the Grid's data source. If the data source is a `System.Data.DataTable` or a `System.Data.DataView`, this method returns a `System.Data.DataRowView` object that represents the focused row. If the data source is a custom list of items, the appropriate list item is returned.

As far as I can see, you are using the `DataTable` as the Grid's data source. If so, you should either change the DataTable to [one of the multiple object's data sources for DevExpress Grid](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/634/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Data-Binding) or use the `DataRow` as a data-transfer unit in form's interoperation.